# Publishing and Distributing using Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

Can Maldivians develop and distribute Android applications in Google Play Store? it is not listed in the supported locations for distribution to Google Play users. So can you still develop and distribute using Google Play while in Maldives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maldives supports Google Play Developer Registration (= you can develop and distribute apps) and does not support registration as a Google Wallet merchant (you can't sell apps or in-app products).

Reference: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/table/3539140

Comment: so i can develop and distribute but cannot really do in app sales or sell my applications huh ?
will i still be able to monetize  through advertising ? using features such as Admob ?

Comment: Correct. You can develop and distribute apps but can't sell apps or in-app products. That said, you can still monetize them using AdMob (it's available in Maldives) or any other way (e.g. Freemium model).

Comment: Thank you so much, there aren't many google play developers in the country nor is it something that's really sort after here..